# Number Validate in Text Box in PHP

Tags: php, post

I need to validate the value of a text box.  The text box is for the customers phone number in the format 0123456789 (ie 10 numbers only and that too live that means while entering number it won't allow user to add any alphabets or special symbols)

The data is sent to a page (validate.php) via a forms POST method.

I want a function that will only accept 10 numbers one after another, no letters or characters.

Comment: Use regular expression- something like \d{10}

Comment: thnx bro... and i already did that but it wont allow me live ( at the time of entering )

Comment: Live? I think you should use client-side validation for 'live' (and by client-side, I mean JavaScript).

Comment: @viru_d_great - Take a look at SO thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">

  function isNumberKey(evt)
      {
         var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
         if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
            return false;

         return true;
      }

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="tel_num" value="" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="10"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use preg_match for example

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}$/', $_POST['your-value']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a regex in your PHP script, as [AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/142822/avd) stated, or you could prevent the user from submitting the form, using the validate plugin of jQuery.

HTML

```
<form name="contact" id="contact">
    <input name="number" id="number" />
</form>
```

jQUery

```
$("#contact").validate({
    rules: {
        number: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            numeric: true
                }
    },
        messages: {
            number: {
                required: "Enter a phone number",
                minlength: "The phone number is too short",
                numeric: "Please enter numeric values only"
            }
        }
})
```

More info at [jQuery/Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It validates the entry on each key input

HTML:

```
<input size="10" maxlength="10" type="text" name="p_len" id="p_len" value="" onkeyup="check(this)" />
```

Javascript:

```
function check(o) {
    v=o.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,''); // remove any whitespace
    if(o=='') {
        return;
    }
    v=v.substr(v.length-1);
    if(v.match(/\d/g)==null) {
        o.value=o.value.substr(0,o.value.length-1).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'');
    }
}
```

It will remove a non-digit input as soon as it is input and length is limited to 10.

Hope this helps.